# how to retrieve multiple values from url and echo them out again with the same id

Tags: php

I know this my sound like a very obvious question however I have been trying to find the right answer I just can't manage to find it.
Please go easy i am an beginner with php.

Here is my code that I send across from my shoppping basket:

```
// Build the query string
$queryString  = "?cmd=_cart";
$queryString .= "&upload=1";
$queryString .= "&charset=utf-8";
$queryString .= "&currency_code=" . urlencode($config['currencyCode']);

foreach ($jcart->get_contents() as $item) {

    $queryString .= '&Description' .  '=' . urlencode($item['name']);
    $queryString .= '&Amount' .  '=' . urlencode($item['price']);
    $queryString .= '&Shipping' .  '=' . urlencode($item['del']);
```

This will out put a url something like:

> http://www.mysite.php?cmd=_cart&upload=1&charset=utf-8&currency_code=GBP&Description=item1&Amount=419.00&Shipping=0.00&Description=Item2&Amount=354.00&Shipping=0.00

If I `echo $Description` I get: `Item2`

I would like to get:

```
Item1, Item 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help is welcome .

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the same name. The second `Description` will always override the first.

Just call the second one `Description2`, or a name which will describe the description value it is storing

Answer (score 0):

What you doing is the same as:

```
 $value = 1;
 $value =2;
```

When you:

```
 echo $value;
```

You will obviously get the value 2, I'm sure you know why. This is because you have 2 descriptions in the url. So one variable over-rides the other. Rather put that data in an array, convert it to JSON (not sure if you can urlencode it straight), urlencode to send it across.

And decode it the other side.

**My point being "find a work around"**

**Edit:**
I would send an array of urlencoded JSON objects(I've never tried to urlencode an array, that is why I would use JSON in my case). But the problem with what you are doing is that the url will eventually be too long. You only have 2 items in it, I wonder how many you going to have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function:

```
function vars2url($array, $parent = ''){
    $params = array();
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v))
            $params[] = vars2url($v, (empty($parent) ? urlencode($k) : $parent . '[' . urlencode($k) . ']'));
        else
            $params[] = (!empty($parent) ? $parent . '[' . urlencode($k) . ']' : urlencode($k)) . '=' . urlencode($v);
    }
    return implode('&', $params);
}
```

Example usage:

```
$params = array(
    'cmd' => '_cart',
    'upload' => 1,
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'currency_code' => $config['currencyCode'],
    'Description' => array('Item1', 'Item2'));
echo vars2url($params);
```

Result:

> cmd=_cart&upload=1&charset=utf-8&cy_code=&Description[0]=Item1&Description[1]=Item2